# Jquery get content not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, my problem is I am using Jquery for a slider and whenever my slide changes I want to get some attribute data using Jquery. So, I am using this HTML code:

```
      <a href="#" data-caption="Nepal"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" data-caption="Ghandruk"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" data-caption="thriller!"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" data-caption="Himalayas!"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" data-caption="Beautiful"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
      <a href="#" data-caption="Chhomrong"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
```

So, when any one of these images is active it automatically gets a class named **active** so, I am trying to use this Jquery to get that active class so, that I can do some work according to the current slide

```
      var x = (($("a.active").data("data-caption")));
```

:[image: This is the output which I am getting out of this I don't know how to extract the highlighted data.]

Comment: In the image you've logged the element `div.gallery.fg-body`, which you've not shown in your question and doesn't seem to relate at all to the jQuery you've shown; please read the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the 'data-' off of the key. data() puts it on there for you when it looks it up.

```
$("a.active").data("caption")
```

```js
console.log($('a.active').data('caption'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-caption="Himalayas!" class="active"><img src="img/01.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: See the Attached Screenshot also. I am trying to access data from that Jquery Object but I am not able to traverse that object.

Comment: What is my answer missing that you are trying to do?  The innerHTML can be gotten with `.html()` and the innerText can be gotten with `.text()`

Comment: I am still getting an object in response to the Script you wrote in console log

Comment: As the active class is generated at run time so, is it possible that the problem is because of that?

Comment: No, I am not setting any object Value to any place in my code.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).html is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:31 I am getting this response while firing $("a.active").data("caption").html()

Comment: Still Getting the same error

Comment: Ok, so I'm confused at this point if `$("a.active").data("caption")` is console logging as your picture in your post, then that element is an array with at least one object in it that should have the innerHTML property on it.

Comment: $("a.active").attr("caption") i just now tried this in console and it worked but It is not working the same with my code.

Comment: When are you performing your logic?  Before or after the flipping gallery plugin initializes?

Comment: After it initializes

Comment: Then I'm not sure what is happening between the point that you perform your logic and the time that you try to do it in the console, but there is something that isn't finished initializing or being setup or something.

Comment: It Worked fine now. Thanks a ton Buddy!!!

Comment: What'd you change?

Comment: I just changed the place where I was calling the jQuery function and it started working properly.